# Magento 2 : Sitemap Generation Warnings - Invalid header line detected

Tags: magento2.2, error, email, exception, sitemaps

I am using magento 2.2.4. The site is working fine. But everyday I got a sitemap error email. The below lines are in the email.

```
Sitemap Generation Warnings

Invalid header line detected
```

Also an exception is logged in to the exception.log.

```
main.CRITICAL: Invalid header line detected {"exception":"[object] (Zend_Http_Exception(code: 0): Invalid header line detected at /home/magento/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Http/Response.php
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an issue with the litemage cache extension. I have upgraded the extension to latest version and the issue is resolved

Reference: [Magento 2: Zend_Http_Exception Invalid header line detected](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/250149/magento-2-zend-http-exception-invalid-header-line-detected)